# BigQuery running in Airflow is running query in incorrect region even though different region is explicitly specified

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to set a `DEFAULT_TABLE_EXPIRATION_DAYS=7` on BigQuery schemas/datasets using a FOR loop. All my datasets are location in multi-region `EU` and I'm getting a list of datasets from the information schema.

Here's the query I planned to use for this:

```
FOR record IN (
                  SELECT schema_name
                  FROM `region-eu`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
                  WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(schema_name, r'^analytics_\d+$')
              )
    DO
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT('''
            ALTER SCHEMA %s
                SET OPTIONS (
                    DEFAULT_TABLE_EXPIRATION_DAYS = 7
                    );
            ''', record.schema_name);
    END FOR;
```

The query should run in Airflow (currently using 1.10.15, running on GCP Cloud Composer 1), once a week. However, when I run the query in Airflow, I receive following error.

```
Not found: Table <project_id>:region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA was not found in location US at [3:19]
```

This is a strange issue, since I'm explicitly querying the `region-eu` information schema tables, but Airflow (or BigQuery) seems to run this query in US instead. I also tried to specify `location='eu'` in the Airflow task, but the same error occurs. When I run the below query separately in Airflow, everything is working and the `SCHEMATA` view is queried successfully.

```
SELECT schema_name
FROM `region-eu`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(schema_name, r'^analytics_\d+$')
```

What's even stranger, I have a similar script, which also queries `region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` and uses a FOR loop, and that script is working without issues.

```
DECLARE start_date_ft, end_date_ft STRING;
DECLARE start_date, end_date DATE;

SET start_date = CURRENT_DATE() - 1;
SET end_date = CURRENT_DATE();

SET start_date_ft = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', start_date);
SET end_date_ft = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', end_date);

FOR record IN (
                  SELECT schema_name, REGEXP_EXTRACT(schema_name, r'\d+') AS ga_property_id
                  FROM `region-eu`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
                  WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(schema_name, r'^analytics_\d+$')
              )
    DO
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT('''
            DELETE
            FROM dataset.table
            WHERE TRUE
              AND event_date >= '%s'
              AND ga_property_id = '%s'
            ;
            ''', CAST(start_date AS STRING), record.ga_property_id);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT('''
            INSERT INTO dataset.table
            SELECT *
            ...
                ''',record.ga_property_id, record.schema_name, record.ga_property_id, start_date_ft, end_date_ft
            );

    END FOR;
```

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I managed to work around the issue by first creating a `TEMP TABLE` which stored information from `region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` and then doing a `FOR` loop over this temporary table.

There was no need to specify a location in Airflow directly. The final script looks like this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE schemas_to_set_expiry AS
SELECT schema_name
FROM `region-eu`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(schema_name, r'^analytics_\d+$');

FOR record IN (SELECT schema_name FROM schemas_to_set_expiry)
    DO
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT('''
            ALTER SCHEMA %s
                SET OPTIONS (
                    DEFAULT_TABLE_EXPIRATION_DAYS = 7
                    );
            ''', record.schema_name);
    END FOR;
```